# Failed to load image in a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, url, uicollectionview, xcode7

I need to show flickr public images in a `UICollectionView`. I have done all the things, but images don't load in the `UICollectionView`. I am new to objective-c. Please help.

```
   authorIds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    dateTaken = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    smallImageUrlArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    largeImageUrlArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    smallImageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 10;
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10;
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(110, 20, 20, 20);
    _collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame collectionViewLayout:layout];
    [_collectionView setDataSource:self];
    [_collectionView setDelegate:self];
    [_collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
    [_collectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:_collectionView];



    - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
      return totalImageNo;
    }


    - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *cellImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];

    cellImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[smallImageUrlArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    //[self.view addSubview:cellImageView];
    [cell.backgroundView addSubview:cellImageView];





   // NSLog(@"%@",[smallImageUrlArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]); //Here can show Img's values correctly

    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor darkGrayColor];
    return cell;
}

    - (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
      return CGSizeMake(160, 160);
    }
```

In below I am fetching Flickr images and storing in array. then want to load the smallImageArray in the UICollection view. but nothing shows up.

```
-(void)fetchFlickrPublicImages
    {
        NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json&tags=data"];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

        NSData *badJSON = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

        NSString *dataAsString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[badJSON bytes]];

        NSString *correctedJSONString = [NSString stringWithString:[dataAsString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange (15, dataAsString.length-15-1)]];
        correctedJSONString = [correctedJSONString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\'" withString:@"'"];

        NSData *correctedData = [correctedJSONString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSError* error;
        NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:correctedData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

        NSArray *images = [json objectForKey:@"items"];

        for (NSDictionary *image in images)
        {
            NSString *authorId = [image objectForKey:@"author_id"];

            [authorIds addObject:(authorId.length > 0 ? authorId: @"Untitled")];

            NSString *largeImageUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[image objectForKey:@"media"] objectForKey:@"m"]];

            NSString *smallImageUrl = [largeImageUrl stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_m" withString:@"_s"];

            [smallImageUrlArray addObject:smallImageUrl];

            [dateTaken addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[image objectForKey:@"date_taken"]]];

            [largeImageUrlArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[image objectForKey:@"media"] objectForKey:@"m"]]];

            totalImageNo = authorIds.count;
        }


        for (int i=0; i< smallImageUrlArray.count; i++) {

            UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                                                        [NSURL URLWithString:[smallImageUrlArray objectAtIndex:i]]]];

            [smallImageArray addObject:image];
        }
        NSLog(@"%@", smallImageArray);

        NSLog(@"%ld", (long)totalImageNo);
       // NSLog(@"authorIds: %@\n\n", authorIds);
       // NSLog(@"photoURLsLareImage: %@\n\n", smallImageUrlArray);
       // NSLog(@"photoURLsLareImage: %@\n\n", largeImageUrlArray);

    }
```

Comment: change this `[cell.backgroundView addSubview:cellImageView];` into `[cell. contentView addSubview:cellImageView];` and try

Answer (score -1):

You should add your UIImageView to the collection view cell's `contentView`, NOT `backgroundView`.

Answer (score -1):

In your code ,

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
UIImageView *cellImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
cellImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[smallImageUrlArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; 
[cell.backgroundView addSubview:cellImageView];  
}
```

you are assigning image as url . but in your method named fetchFlickrPublicImages where you are downloading images directly.

better you write code like

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
UIImageView *cellImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
cellImageView.image =(UIImage*)[smallImageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
[cell.contentView addSubView cellImageView];
}
```